# Установка Node.js на GNU/Linux x64. BASH не видит (перестал видеть) бинарник

Tags: linux, node.js, bash

Скачал с официального сайта Current-версию Node.js. Распаковал архив в `~/.local/bin/`. В переменной окружения $PATH этот каталог охватывается. Все заработало. На команду `node` терминал откликается. На `npm` тоже (они лежат в одной директории). Версия, которую я установил - 7.9.0. На следующий день решил проверить версию Node'а - выдало стабильную 6.10.2. Я немного опешил, ведь я ее не устанавливал вообще. Ввел `which node`, чтобы узнал, откуда он ее взял. Оказалось, что он нашел эту версию Node'а в `/usr/bin/`. При поиске этого каталога для удаления нажатием `tab` ничего не выводилось. Простым просмотром с помощью команды `ls` тоже. Однако удаление при помощи `sudo rm -R` действительно удалило эту папку (или это был файл?). На `node` терминал откликаться перестал.

После этого я решил снова скачать точно current-версию node'а, как и в прошлый раз закинул распакованный архив в `~/.local/bin`, но теперь BASH в упор не видит эти 2 бинарника: `node` и `npm`.

Привожу `echo $PATH`:

> /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/matt/.local/bin:/home/matt/bin:/home/matt/.local/bin:/home/matt/bin

Как видно, путь, по которому находится `node` проверяется.

**Собственно, вопросы:**
  1. Откуда после установки Current-версии 7.9.0 в `~/.local/bin/` взялась LTS-версия 6.10.0 в `/usr/bin/`?
  2. Почему теперь BASH не видит бинарников, расположенных в `~/.local/bin/[папка с нодом]`?
  3. Как грамотно все это дело установить (заставить BASH видеть node, например) и, если необходимо, полностью почистить систему от прошлых установок?

И да, терминал я перезапускал и даже обновлял `.bash_profile`. Безрезультатно.

И еще, система изначально была абсолютно чистая, из репозиториев никаких node'ов не устанавливалось и до этого их не было на машине вообще.

Comment: Я тебе для Ubuntu написал, вообще-то. Но не нравится - дело хозяйское. Гы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Были найдены ответы на 2 последних вопроса:
Дело в том, что `.bash_profile` не подгружается при открытии терминала. Для этого, как было сказано на просторах интернета, необходимо создать отдельный файл `.profile`. Но у меня и этот файл автоматически не подгружался. Поэтому выполнение файла `.profile`, который содержал данные о местонахождении Node'а, я инициализировал в `.bashrc`. Теперь при запуске терминала выполняется `.bashrc`, который, в свою очередь, завершает свое выполнение и выполняет `.profile`. Однако теперь рекурсивный поиск в поддиректориях не производится и путём к Node'у является непосредственно путь до бинарника. Почему раньше этого не требовалось - не знаю.

Comment: То есть вы не понимаете всей этой кухни, и сделали из одной проблемы сразу несколько...

Comment: @0andriy почему же? Проблема решена вроде. А "всю эту кухню", пожалуй, да, действительно слабо понимаю.